# How to add languages to Guest session ?

Tags: 12.04

I want to add Arabic language to guest season, because there is only English, but i can't  do it.
Can any body help me with that problem ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a long standing bug, see [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm-guest-session/+bug/463622).

There are several workarounds, see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession), but, that wiki page applies to 14.04 only.

For earlier versions of Ubuntu, there is an old wiki page [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession/old).

And on that page is a program you can install, [guest-session-prefs-lightdm-0.12.tar.gz](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=guest-session-prefs-lightdm-0.12.tar.gz)

To install you would run:

```
tar -xf guest-session-prefs-lightdm-0.12.tar.gz
cd guest-session-prefs-lightdm-0.12
sudo ./install.sh
```

It then runs when you log into the guest session.

> If you launch a guest session right after having installed guest-session-prefs, you are prompted to choose between English and Swedish.

They also state:

> For those of you who want to be able to select language, the language related code ought to be useful. If one language (e.g. French) is enough, but the launching regular session might be run in some other language, the code in /etc/guest-session/prepare.sh can be exchanged for:

```
echo "fr_FR" > /tmp/guest-session-lang
```

Change "fr_FR" to you language.

If all that fails, from the bug report,

> The tutorial I mentioned shows how the guest session language can be set irrespective of the system default. The key lines of code (in prefs.sh) are:

```
echo "Language=$long.utf8" >> /var/cache/gdm/$USER/dmrc
echo "export LANGUAGE=$short" >> $HOME/.profile
```

If all of the above fails, I suggest you post on the bug report.